# Inserting date during compilation of HTML5 project

Tags: html

I have an HTML5 `TypeScript` project, containing an index.html:

```html
<html>
    ...
    <body>
    <div class="footer">xxx</div>
    ...
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I compile my project using Visual Studio, I would like to change the "xxx" to the current date. I have tried using XmlPoke, but since I have JavaScript (omitted above due to space), XmlPoke cannot identify that as valid XML and the task fails.

Comment: show us your code

Comment: "during compilation" -- do you mean on page load? Please show us your code. Right now, your question is too broad.

Comment: Edited the main post and added some code and a better explanation.